# Update Column Value if the column Value contains and replace

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a requirement where, I am trying to write a query that looks into my column Values and if a particular value is found then it changes them.

For Example  if ABC or DEF is found then it is replaced by " "

```
DatabaseName: TestDB
TableName: Table1
```

Actual Data in the Table1

```
ColA
Test
Test1 ABC
Test2 DEF
```

This needs to be changed to something like,

```
ColA
Test
Test1
Test2
```

Comment: 1) Will it always be ABC/DEF or will it be other random stuff? 2) Will the value before the ABC/DEF stuff ever contain a space? 3) Will the value before ABC/DEF ever contain the chars ABC/DEF?

Comment: I understood the solution from Juan's answer. Thanks. I will accept his answer once the mandatory 10 minutes gets over.

Comment: what @dfundako mean is if you have something like `milky way` and replace `milk` can have undesired results. So just be carefull

Comment: Yes, In my case I am changing very limited number of cities and they don't contain each other name. Thanks Guys :)

Comment: Where you looking for the T-SQL or U-SQL answer? Note that in U-SQL's current implementation, there is no UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update Table1
set ColA = replace(replace(ColA, 'ABC', ''), 'DEF', '')
```